# multiple values within HTML 5 progress bar

Tags: progress

Is there a way to have multiple values within the HTML 5 progress bar? I tried using :after pseudo elements, but that doesn't work with progress .

I would like to have one value as 'Completed', as well as another that would be 'In Progress'. An example would be:

```html
<progress value="33.3" value2="10" max="100"></progress>
```

Where 33 is completed %, and 10 is In Progress %.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there's no way to do this using HTML5. W3 specifies only one value for the progress bar. https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/progress
When you set more than one value, only the first one will be displayed.

You can use nested divs or bootstrap's progress bars, which is the same, but simple & beautiful right from the box.